# Unity, loading image from Sqlite

Tags: image, sqlite, unity-game-engine, byte, blob

hi guys this is my first time using Sqlite, i managed to retrieve the text and display it, however the image shows a red question mark even tho i followed this : [unity sqlite tutorial](https://answers.unity.com/questions/743400/database-sqlite-setup-for-unity.html)

here is my code :

```
private void readQuestionsFromDB(){

    string conn = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/quizdb.s3db"; //Path to database.
 IDbConnection dbconn;
 dbconn = (IDbConnection) new SqliteConnection(conn);
 dbconn.Open(); //Open connection to the database.
 IDbCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();
 string sqlQuery = "SELECT id, statement, answer, image " + "FROM questions";
 dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
 IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

 while (reader.Read())
 {
    string statement = reader.GetString(1);

    answerint = reader.GetInt32(2);

    byte[] img = (byte[])reader["image"];

    Question q = new Question(statement, answer, img);
    questions.Add(q);

 }
 reader.Close();
 reader = null;
 dbcmd.Dispose();
 dbcmd = null;
 dbconn.Close();
 dbconn = null;

}
```

Then i try to display the image from the start method :

```
readQuestionsFromDB();  

   statement.text = questions[0].statement;

   Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(800,400); //image is 800/400
    tex.LoadImage(questions[0].image);
    image.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0,0,tex.width,tex.height),new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
```

Here is the outcome :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8OYf.png)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you check the url/path that you are getting from the database?

Comment: the url of the image? no i didn't, how can i do it please?

Comment: Looks like the image is a byte array. Can you Debug.Log confirm that questions[0].image isn't null or empty? Also, what's the Question class contents?

Comment: yes i checked the size of the byte array, as well as the boolean returned by tex.LoadImage() which returns true.

The question class has a String for the statement, a boolean for the answer (true or false) and a byte array.

Comment: Ok, Try this [Texturfe2d.LoadRawTextureData](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html)